# SharePoint List formula

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, custom-list, calculated-column-formula

I need help on below list.

Pur No.  Stock Qty, Sold Qty, Balance Qty.

001        500

First time when user enter the sold Qty it will work

```
(Stock Qty - Sold Qty = Balance Qty)
```

so if sold Qty is equal to Stock Qty then Balance will be zero.

But for the same No. if Sold Qty is less than Stock Qty so user will again do the entry in the same row. For example first time sold Qty 300 and second time sold Qty 200.

so for this in list first entry 300 Qty it will work like

```
(Stock Qty (500) - Sold Qty (300) = Balance Qty(200))
```

and in second entry user will click on edit option to edit the row and when user will enter Qty 200 in sold Qty column it will deduct from Balance Qty not from Stock Qty like

```
(Sold Qty (200) - Balance Qty (200) = Balance Qty (0)).
```

Can anyone please help how to write the formula for this in SharePoint OOTB List.

Comment: You need to some how store each transaction. ie. you need to store the previous Sold Qty then only you can do something like this. For that you need to use at minimum 2 lists.

Comment: Thanks Amal, I also thought to create two list but I got confused how to store Sold Qty in multiple lots and store Balance Qty to call in another list using Lookup column with Sold Date. If you provide detail only for these three columns with two list as example it will be easy for me to understand.I'm not getting any example for this scenario please.